# create a union of 3 files with different column headers and rows

Tags: python, r, merge

I have three text files with different number of rows and columns. The column names are different in each file. There are some overlapping rows and many unique rows.

file1.txt

```
SNP CHROM   POS ref alt GT  info    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5
snp1    1   1   A   c   .   PR  0/0 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/0
snp2    2   2   t   a   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1
snp3    3   3   g   t   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/0
snp4    1   4   c   g   .   PR  0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp5    1   5   a   c   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp6    2   6   t   a   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp7    5   7   g   t   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp8    6   8   c   g   .   PR  0/0 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp9    8   9   a   c   .   PR  1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 1/1
snp10   13  10  t   a   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
```

file2.txt

```
SNP CHROM   POS ref alt GT  info    sample6 sample7 sample8 sample9 sample10    sample11
snp1    1   1   A   c   .   PR  0/0 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/0 0/0
snp2    2   2   t   a   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1
snp4    3   3   g   t   .   PR  0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp5    1   4   c   g   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp7    1   5   a   c   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp8    2   6   t   a   .   PR  0/0 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp10   5   7   g   t   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp11   6   8   c   g   .   PR  1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1
snp12   8   9   a   c   .   PR  1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1
snp13   13  10  t   a   .   PR  1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1
```

file3.txt

```
SNP CHROM   POS ref alt GT  info    sample12    sample13    sample14    sample15    sample16    sample17    sample18    sample19
snp1    1   1   A   c   .   PR  0/0 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1
snp8    2   2   t   a   .   PR  0/0 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp10   3   3   g   t   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp11   1   4   c   g   .   PR  1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/0
snp12   1   5   a   c   .   PR  1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/0
snp13   2   6   t   a   .   PR  1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/0
snp14   5   7   g   t   .   PR  1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/0
snp15   6   8   c   g   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp16   8   9   a   c   .   PR  1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/0
snp17   13  10  t   a   .   PR  0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
snp18   11  11  g   t   .   PR  1/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/0
```

What I want to do is: create a union of all three row names and union of all column headers from all the three files. Then I would like to fill up the column values based on three files. For example: if a row is found in file, then enter the values corresponding to that specific column header. If row is not found in file 1, then enter "./." . fill up the entire table based on the three files.
this is what I have tried so far in R:

```
list(file1, file2, file3) %>%
reduce(full_join) %>%
mutate(across(everything(), replace_na, "./."))
```

However since I hvae to join 1000 columns and about 22 million rows, I run into memory issues in R. Is there an time efficient way to accomplish this in R or python or bash?

Comment: Since the SNP position is your index and the support count is the real data, maybe you can try save the support counts in sparse matrices, then try to merge them. In R it's featured in package `Matrix`,